# Gradient of gradient and laplacian of one-dimensional vector give different results in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 1-dimensional vector which is:

```
p = [1 3 6 10 16 18 29];

laplace = del2(p);
px= gradient(p);
pxx=gradient(px);
```

Since it is one-dimensional, laplacian of the vector must be equal to gradient of gradient. However they give completely different results.

```
laplace =    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.5000   -1.0000    2.2500    5.5000
pxx =    0.5000    0.7500    1.2500    0.2500    0.7500    3.5000    4.5000
```

Comment: Might be that `del2` assumes a linear spacing of `1` once, whilst `gradient` does this twice

Comment: No way, I tried different spacing, but result does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler example:

```
gradient(gradient((1:10).^2))
1, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 1
```

and

```
4*del2((1:10).^2)
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

So `gradient` treats the first and last values differently (consequently `gradient(gradient())` has different first two and last two entries, `del2` extrapolates linearly).

`del2` must be multiplied by 4 to be compatible with `gradient(gradient())`

And if you look inside the code (`edit del2` or `edit gradient`) you see that gradient takes a symmetrical difference for interior points (taking the previous and the next point equally). `del2` does the same but only once. Therefore `gradient(gradient())`smoothes a bit more.

However if I smooth the result of `del2`with a kernel like `[0.25 0.5 0.25]` then I can get exactly the same results as `gradient(gradient())`.

```
p = [1 3 6 10 16 18 29];
conv(4 * del2(p), [0.5,1,0.5] / 2, 'same')
0.75, 1, 1.25, 0.25, 0.75, 9, 13.25
gradient(gradient(p))
0.5, 0.75, 1.25, 0.25, 0.75, 3.5, 4.5
```

Please note that the central three values are identical, the two border values on each side are different because the borders are treated differently.